# Custom yeoman generator problems with the npminstall function

Tags: json, npm, yeoman-generator

I've been checking some guides about the creation of a custom yeoman generator.

At the end, I have this:

```
runNpm: function(){
var done = this.async();
this.npmInstall("", function(){
    console.log("\nEverything Setup !!!\n");
    done();
});
```

which I assume works as if I input npm install for the package.json dependencies.
The problem is I get this error:

```
5 error install Couldn't read dependencies
6 error package.json ENOENT, open 'C:\Users\Fabritzio\Desktop\donald\package.json'
6 error package.json This is most likely not a problem with npm itself.
6 error package.json npm can't find a package.json file in your current directory.
7 error System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
8 error command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe""C:\\ProgramFiles\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
9 error cwd C:\Users\Fabritzio\Desktop\donald
10 error node -v v0.10.30
11 error npm -v 1.4.21
12 error path C:\Users\Fabritzio\Desktop\donald\package.json
13 error code ENOPACKAGEJSON
14 error errno 34
15 verbose exit [ 34, true ]
```

this is the package.json

```
{
"name": "usaria",
"description": "Small scope system using firebase and angularjs.",
"author": "Donald Villegas",
"contributors": [],
"dependencies": [],
"version": "0.1.0",
"devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.5",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.5.0"
},
"repository": {
  "type": "git",
  "url": "git://github.com/FabVillegas/usaria"
}}
```

Comment: I can create all the folders, and files.

Comment: If I create all the files, and then in the cmd run npm install, it will read the dependencies and correctly install them

Comment: Isn't "dependencies" supposed to be an object, not an array?

Comment: I've been checking guides, so I really dont know.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it, It creates everything without an ERROR tag:

Changed this

```
runNpm: function(){
    var done = this.async();
    this.npmInstall("", function(){
    console.log("\nEverything Setup !!!\n");
    done();
});
```

To this

```
runNpm: function(){
    this.npmInstall();
    this.bowerInstall("angularfire");
    console.log("\nEverything Setup !!!\n");
});
```